# Angular: HostBinding to custom component property

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind to a property on a parent component from a child component but it's not working.  Here's the code:

**Parent**

`myProp: string;`  (I've also tried `@Input() myProp: string;`)

**Child**

`@HostBinding('myProp')  prop1: string;`

The error I'm getting is ***Can't bind to 'myProp' since it isn't a known property of 'child-component'*** which makes sense, because isn't the idea behind HostBinding that it should look for the property on the **parent**, not the child?

I've seen lots of examples of binding to `class`, `style` and *attributes* on the parent/host, but nothing for custom properties, other than mentions that it is possible.  The Angular docs also state [`HostBinding` takes an optional parameter that specifies the property name of the host element that will be updated.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c2dbc55f115eb259a6d90e2b45ed61c329258c22/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L949)

Does anyone have an example they can share of this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might have been a bug - although think it's considered working-as-designed.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16797

The properties were not binding, only the class., attr. and style.